# Fulltext search vs standard database search

Tags: database, search, full-text-search

What I want to know what is difference between fulltext searching (searching data in files) and standard database searching (LIKE, IN ect).

What I notice here is that in files you don't have data types, but in database you can define data types for particular data.

I am interested in what kind of search is faster and what are advantages and disadvantages of both.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a few advantages to full text searching.

**Indexing:**

Something like:

```
WHERE Foo LIKE '%Bar';
```

Cannot take advantage of an index.  It has to look at every single row, and see if it matches.  A fulltext index, however, can.  In fact, fulltext indexes can offer a lot more flexibility in terms of the order of matching words, how close those words are together, etc.

**Stemming:**

A fulltext search can *stem* words.  If you search for *run*, you can get results for "ran" or "running".  Most fulltext engines have stem dictionaries in a variety of languages.

**Weighted Results:**

A fulltext index can encompass multiple columns.  For example, you can search for "peach pie", and the index can include a title, keywords, and a body.  Results that match the title can be *weighted* higher, as more relevant, and can be sorted to show near the top.

**Disadvantages:**

A fulltext index can potentially be *huge*, many times larger than a standard B-TREE index.  For this reason, many hosted providers who offer database instances *disable* this feature, or at least charge extra for it.  For example, last I checked, Windows Azure did not support fulltext queries.

Fulltext indexes can also be slower to update.  If the data changes a lot, there might be some lag updating indexes compared to standard indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is useful for me. But I always wondering how fulltext search works in background. What I need is some reference to learn about it. I would like to know the patterns by which all that works.

Comment: That's a huge topic, and it differs between SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.

Comment: Anything would helped me, no matter if it is for SQL Server, Oracle or Postgres. If you know some reference I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe read up on GiN and GiST indexes?  Here's some [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-indexes.html) documentation.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Just to correct, MS FTS can't search for leading wild card search. It can't work for the case your mentioned i.e. '%Bar'. However it can for 'Bar%'